# Is there a limit on NSURLConnection usage within an iOS app?

Tags: ios, heroku, nsurlconnection, restkit

Whenever I run into the following error in my iOS app with RestKit 0.10.x underlying framework for REST~ful JSON requests:

```
Error Domain = NSURLErrorDomain
Code = -1003
A server with the specified hostname could not be found
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey = https://my.herokuapp.com:443/me?i=am,
NSErrorFailingURLKey = https://my.herokuapp.com:443/me?i=am
```

I find myself scratching my head because the URL that is supposed to be problematic, happens to be in the public domain and works just fine when I run the same operation again via the app. On the Heroku server side logs I don't see any request timeout issues either.

So my question is:

1. Is there a limit on NSURLConnection usage within an iOS app?
2. Or is it just a flaky thing in iOS that happens to everyone and should be worked around by re-trying the request upon error?

Comment: Hi pulkitsinghal, did you solve this problem? I am facing the same issue. Can you help me?

Comment: No I did not solve this problem, just a bunch of catch and retries.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue ? I am also facing this same error.Please suggest.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan - nope, just gave up and moved to HTML5 based apps

Answer (score 1):

The network can only handle a limited number of concurrent connection before it gets flooded and all do the in-progress connections will fail. You should limit the number of concurrent connection to perhaps 3. This can be done on the request queue of the http client of the RestKit object manager.